# Drop all databases that have under certain number of tables

Tags: mysql, database, drop-database

I have a MYSQL server with lots of inactive databases. All this "dead" DBs have under 109 tables each, so I'm looking for a way to drop all of them at once, but haven't found a way to make this. The other way I'm thinking I could delete all of them is by dropping all the databases that don't have X table (where X is the latest table added to our model).

Comment: Dare I ask how many is "lots"?

Comment: I think you'd better write a simple script in whatever language you like, and count the number of table for each db (show tables) after asking for the db list (show databases) !!!

Comment: What scripting languages are you familiar with? A combination of `USE DATABASE x` and `SHOW TABLES` might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the databases with the following query:

```
select schema_name
from information_schema.tables
group by schema_name
having count(*) < 109
```

You can then use the list of schema_name to create "drop database" commands in a tool such as Excel.  Or, put in a cursor to cycle through them.  Or read them into a scripting language of your preference to do the drop.